# How should a Redis ordered and limit sized collection should be managed?

Tags: redis

I'm keeping a leaderboard using Redis **sorted sets**, so I'm using `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE` in order to get the top 10 users.

My keys inside the sorted set look like `user-id:xxxx` and the value it's the points user have got, integers.

When I retrieve the highest 10 users (`ZREVRANGEBYSCORE general-ranking +inf -inf LIMIT 0 10`) I also need to show the data from those users, that information is stored at MongoDB in a `Users` collection.

So, I ***can not*** go to MongoDB to ask for top 10 users data on every leaderboard change. That would be overkill, so I thought *I can store the highest 30 or 50 users data (giving an offset) the way when a new value might come in, it will replace any value if needed in order to keep a fixed size*. I think this way I could reduce the number of operations against MongoDB and improve performance.

So I know there's **lists, hashes and sets** in Redis, but I'm not sure what's best combiation of data types and commands to achieve this, and what's more, they're supposed to be strings (case of sets and lists) and they don't seem to be order capable. I only think trim commants may help to keep a fixed size.

**What I need, conceptually**

Let's say I store a 2 sized list of users, so I got:

- `{user: "Akira", points: 10}`
- `{user: "Luca": points: 3}`

If I then add `{user: "Diego", points: 9248}`, that would remove element with 3 points and the list would be:

- `{user: "Diego": points: 9248}`
- `{user: "Akira", points: 10}`

Any suggestion, idea or alternative?

Answer (score 2):

First, use `ZREVRANGE general-rankings 0 9` to get back the top 10.

Secondly, after every `ZADD`, just do `ZREMRANGEBYRANK general-rankings 0 -10` to keep it capped to the top 10.

Comment: That is not really *the problem*, the problem is that I gotta store other data and if the top changes, I don't want to read to MongoDB every time

Comment: I suppose you could also use a string or a hash to store the actual data for that user whenever your adding the score. Just remember to remove it if you're kicking the user out of the leaderboard.